# How to configure SXA Search Box to support tab or enter completion?

Tags: sxa

Here is what I have setup:

**Insurance Item Template:**

- Title - Single-line Text
- InsuredStates - Multilist pointing to a list of states such as (Texas)
- Inherits from the _Searchable template in SXA

I have a tree structure like so:

[image: Sample Insurance]

The page contains three components:

1. Search Box with a scope set to the root Insurance folder
2. Search Results with a scope set to the Urgent Care folder
3. Search Results with a scope set to the Physical Therapy folder

The rendering variant is setup to show the state names. The *StateName* field exists on the state item as the fullname version (also has an abbrev.).

[image: Rendering Variant]

How do I get the tab completion to populate the search box? Hitting *enter*, *tab*, or clicking does not autocomplete. Hitting *enter* will however trigger a search with the text currently in the box.

[image: No tab completion]

How do I get the page to load without any search results? This appears on first page load.

[image: Populated results]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the final solution I came up with. Thank you Alan for the help.

#### Tab Completion

*How do I get the tab completion to populate the search box?*

We took a different approach by attaching to the click event for the menu and blur event for the input. See the gist [here](https://gist.github.com/michaellwest/a055d1fe4a74c3be73a334f8d709fddc).

#### Hide Search Results

*How do I get the page to load without any search results?*

I blogged about how I accomplished the hiding of the search box [here](https://michaellwest.blogspot.com/2017/11/improve-experience-for-designers-in-sxa.html).

Here are the basics of the approach:

- Add styles to the theme and include them in the Style Selector for components.
- Add scripts to monitor the change of Url hash and toggle visibility when certain conditions are met.

The gist [here](https://gist.github.com/michaellwest/24532142d3564c289aefd834cb3916db/) should help you get past the initial hurdle of writing the styles and code. I do however recommend you read the blog post.

Answer (score 3):

I am afraid you are not able to address your needs without custom code right now.

**How do I get the tab completion to populate the search box?**

There is no way to configure such behaviour right now. If you want you could create your own `component-search-box.js` and implement additional behaviour for tab key

**Search Box** rendering use [typeahead.js](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/)

```js
typeahead = this.$el.find(".search-box-input").typeahead({
    hint: true,
    highlight: true,
    minLength: 2
}, {
    source: inst.model.get("searchEngine").ttAdapter(),
    displayKey: function () {
        return inst.$el.find(".search-box-input.tt-input").val();
    },
    templates: {
        suggestion: function (data) {
            return '<div class="sugesstion-item">' + data.html + '</div>';
        }
    }
}).on('typeahead:selected', function (event, datum) {
    var link = $(datum.html).find("a");

    if (link.length) {
        window.location.href = $(link[0]).attr("href");
    }
});
```

Once you click `Enter`/`Tab`, `typeahead:selected` event will be executed.

**How do I get the page to load without any search results? This appears on first page load.**

This is how search service currently works. It gets results and feed with them all available renderings on a page.

That way you will get facets without need to perform any action, which is good ( in most cases).

**Search Results** rendering contains something like that in his code (`component-search-results.js`)

```js
XA.component.search.vent.on("results-loaded", this.resultsLoaded.bind(this));
```

If you want specifically block **Search Results** from loading data, try to add your custom code somewhere there.

Comment: Thanks Alan. I'll give that a try. Also, I noticed that the template above misspells the word "suggestion".